# Cookies and session nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, session

I created Api server using nodejs and the client side using reactjs,
the client run in url:5000 and client run to url:3000, Run separately.
A client party sends requests to a server side and it returns to it.
i create a session in server , when i connected using login function i return some token using jwt, and i return the token to client, but the problem in client browser i don't have a session.id

this is my code appjs

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const resource = require('./resources/en-US');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // For legacy browser support
}

const authRouter = require('./routes/auth-router');
const adminRouter = require('./routes/admin-router');

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
// app.use(cookieParser());

const http = require('http').createServer(app);

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const store = new MongoStore({
  uri : process.env.MONGODB_URL,
  collection:'session',
});

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET_KEY,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: store,
  cookie: { secure: true,httpOnly:true }
}))

app.use('/api', authRouter);
app.use('/api', adminRouter);

mongoose
.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL,{
  useNewUrlParser:true,
  useCreateIndex:true,
  useUnifiedTopology:true
})
  .then(() => console.log('connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))

http.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

and when i go to other route in Api server, and try to print the req.session i don see my session with store data.

please i need a help,
What is the problem ?

Comment: your cookies configuration have ```secure: true``` which requires your server to be https not http.

Comment: this is not work.

Comment: can you show the client side code where you are making request to the server.

Comment: i write client code with new Answer

Answer (score 0):

this is a client request:

```
export const authenticationLogin = async (data) => {
    const {email , password} = data;
    console.log("log in controller")
    try{
        return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
            axios(
                {
                    url:"/login",
                    method : "POST",
                    data: {
                        email  : email,
                        password: password
                    },
                    withCredentials: true
                }
                ).then( async (data) => {
                    console.log("after responce feching")
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = data.data.token;
                    console.log(data);
                    debugger;
                    resolve(data.data);
                }).catch(error => {
                    reject(error)
                })
        })
    }catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: ```axios.post(url, {email, password}, {withCredentials: true}).then(...........```